# Using serializeArray() method to verify form data on Cypress for Angular App

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-material, cypress

So I am writing a test to validate the data entered on a form for an Angular app using Cypress and the serializeArray() method. This is my first time using **serializeArray()** The testing files are not within the web app, but are in their own separate project folder.

This is how the form is set up in Angular:

```html
    <div class="column">
           <mat-card-content>
               <mat-form-field>
                  <div class ="mat-mdc-form-field">
                       <mat-select formcontrolname="Option1">
                        "USA"
                       </mat-select>
                       <mat-select formcontrolname="Option2">
                       "Canada"
                       </mat-select>
                       <mat-select formcontrolname="Option3">
                       "Mexico"
                       </mat-select>
                  </div class ="mat-mdc-form-field">
               </mat-form-field>
           </mat-card-content>
    </div class="column">
```

This is how I have the assertion written:

```js
cy.get("form")
     .invoke("serializeArray")
     .should("deep.equal", [
     {
         name: "Option1",
         value: "USA"
     },
     {
          name: "Option2",
          value: "Canada"
     },
     {
          name: "Option3",
          value: "Mexico"
     }
]);
```

When I run the test, it is telling me it is failing with the following message: **assertexpected [] to deeply equal [ Array(3) ]**

However, when I check console in dev tools it looks like the data went through.
[image]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  From the looks of it, the test is telling me that the array is empty, but the console is telling me otherwise. At least that's what I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery method `serializeArray` only works with `<form>` but angular material gives you custom elements which are not supported.

You can roll your own process

```js
cy.get('mat-form-field')
  .find('mat-select')
  .then($matSelects => {
    return [...$matSelects].map(matSelect => 
      ({
        name: matSelect.getAttribute('formcontrolname'),
        value: matSelect.innerText.trim().replace(/"/g, '')
      })
    )
  })
  .should("deep.equal", [
    { name: "Option1", value: "USA" },
    { name: "Option2", value: "Canada" },
    { name: "Option3", value: "Mexico" },
  ])
```

This passes for your sample fragment, but note that `serializeArray` applies to all these form controls:

```js
rsubmitterTypes = /^(?:submit|button|image|reset|file)$/i,
rsubmittable = /^(?:input|select|textarea|keygen)/i,
rcheckableType = ( /^(?:checkbox|radio)$/i )
```

so you might have to extend the code a lot more to handle other `mat-*` versions.

Also note there's some funk around the values, so I added `.trim().replace(/"/g, '')`.

This would not be possible if you used `serializeArray`, even if the HTML used regular elements (non `mat-*` versions).